# d3 Wheel of Fortune

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create an interactive wheel of fortune using d3.js that can work on a mobile device.  Here is what I have been working on so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/JBJ1odoGvfWFODuIRqKZ

```
svg.on("mousemove", function(d) {
    if (isDown){
      var angleDeg = Math.atan2(lastY - d3.event.y, lastX - d3.event.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
      lastX = d3.event.x;
      lastY = d3.event.y;
      curAngle = angleDeg;
      svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ") rotate(" + curAngle + "," + 0 + "," + 0 + ")");
    }
  });
```

Right now I am trying to make it so that you can click-drag the pie chart slices and "spin" it around as long as the mouse is down.  I am using Math.atan2 to get the angle between two points on the circle during the mousemove, and changing the pie chart angle accordingly.  It seems that what I have is almost there, but there is a lag/jitter.  Is there something I can do to smoothen this so that it would look like this? : http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/pie2d_5/

Ideally, in the long run, I want the mouseup event to create some sort of velocity for the spin, and whatever the slice that points upward is to be able to be queried.

But for now I am just trying to create a smooth drag-along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why yours is 'jittery' is due to you using the mouse coordinates in relation to one another. What you want to do is use a stationary point, i.e the center of the wheel.

So instead of updating lastX and lastY with d.event.x/y just keep this as :

```
var lastX = width/2; //center points of circle
var lastY = height/2;
```

And use this in your algorithm like so :

```
if (isDown) {
     var thisX = d3.event.x - lastX,
       thisY = d3.event.y - lastY;
     var angleDeg = Math.atan2(lastY - d3.event.y, lastX - d3.event.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
     svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ") rotate(" + angleDeg + "," + 0 + "," + 0 + ")");
   }
```

I have put this on JSFiddle as plnkr wasn't working correctly, with the mouse events and so on : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/ourpo8p7/1/

Even this is not perfect.

Basically what is happening here is, its getting the mouse coordinates and rotating to that coordinate. But you dont want this, you only want it to move when you move the mouse, and even then you only want it to move by the amount you move the cursor, not jump to the cursor (if that even makes sense :P ).

So what you have to do is start at 0, if you move cursor when mouse is down, save position of rotation, so when you start again you can start where you left off. This is hard to explain.

Anyway when mouse is down, save the angle between mouse coordinates and center of circle :

```
var thisX = d3.event.x - lastX,
     thisY = d3.event.y - lastY;
   curAngle = Math.atan2(lastY - d3.event.y, lastX - d3.event.x)  
   if (curAngle < 0) curAngle += 2 * Math.PI; //make sure its positive
   curAngle = curAngle * 180 / Math.PI; //change to degrees
```

Now on mouse move you have to take this value away from the calculated angle so you start at 0, but add the last angle (if any) calculated when you rotated the wheel.

```
 var thisX = d3.event.x - lastX,
       thisY = d3.event.y - lastY;
     angleDeg = Math.atan2(lastY - d3.event.y, lastX - d3.event.x) // * 180 / Math.PI) - curAngle
     if (angleDeg < 0) angleDeg += 2 * Math.PI;
     angleDeg = angleDeg * 180 / Math.PI;
     angleDeg = angleDeg - curAngle + finishAngle; //reset to 0 and add last rotation calculated
     if (angleDeg < 0) angleDeg += 360;
     d3.select('#degrees').text(Math.round(angleDeg))
     svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ") rotate(" + angleDeg + "," + 0 + "," + 0 + ")");
```

And finally, work out angle of rotation to use above when `mouseup`

```
 finishAngle = angleDeg;
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/v8xce8k3/1/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response!  That makes so much sense and it works so well.

Comment: I also wanted to ask if you knew there was a way to do the same thing for touch events.  Is there an X,Y for touchstart/end events?

Comment: @QuantumRich take a look at this example http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/9e6b87735d2da05813e3